# HTTP 1.1 Expect header handshake

Tags: python, http

According http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.3 client has to wait for 100 (Continue) status, before making POST (on HTTP 1.1 server that requires this header).

I can't understand how can Python do this. For example:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(url)
conn.putrequest('POST', page)
conn.putheader(...)
conn.putheader('Expect', '100-continue')
conn.endheaders()
```

Now, I don't see other options then send the data:

```
conn.send(data)
```

in which case I get error, when asking for response:

```
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

How can I ask for status 100, so that I can send the data?

Comment: I don't think `httplib` supports this (very well); see the discussion in [this `requests` ticket](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/713) (specifically the *and can close the socket early in a way that breaks httplib* remark).

Comment: If you read the exception message, you will see that the connection was aborted. Is the network okay? Did you pull a network cable? Is there a firewall with DPI that stops `POST` http requests?

Comment: I guess we can't expect meaningful exception in this case. I don't have problem with with my network, and same code in Java for example works as expected.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, do you know of another library that supports this header?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: The server can close the socket early if an `Expect` header was set. No need for a network problem there.

Comment: @theta: Augie Fackler (durin42) mentions [httpplus](https://code.google.com/p/httpplus/), but I have not tried anything in this direction myself. A quick glance at the code does show promise.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, but then you wouldn't get an "connection aborted" socket error, would you?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: If httplib closed the connection because the remote server closed it early, *then* tried to send something on the connection then you'd get that error.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks! :) httpplus works correctly: `conn.request('POST', path, body, headers={...}, expect_continue=True)`

Comment: @theta: Okay, then I'll summarize my finding in an answer. :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `httplib` supports this (very well); see the discussion in [this requests ticket](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/713), specifically

> and can close the socket early in a way that breaks httplib

The author of that comment, Augie Fackler (durin42) also mentions his own [`httpplus` library](https://code.google.com/p/httpplus/).

A quick glance at the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/httpplus/source/browse/httpplus/__init__.py#210) shows promise that *it* does handle `Expect: 100-Continue` correctly:

```
# handle 100-continue response
hdrs, body = self.raw_response.split(self._end_headers, 1)
http_ver, status = hdrs.split(' ', 1)
if status.startswith('100'):
    self.raw_response = body
    self.continued = True
    logger.debug('continue seen, setting body to %r', body)
    return
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I would never have found this library without your comment here. Using httpplus instead of urllib2 solved a similar issue I had where I needed support for 100 continue.