# How to send a 100 continue request in the library requests

Tags: python, python-requests

How to send the following HTTP request in requests?

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
```

I thought about getting the responsible socket inside the requests module and do it manually. Something like along this:

```
requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool.socket.socket.send(b'HTTP/1.1 100 Continue')
```

But that's not clean (and won't work either).

And ideas?

Comment: See https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/713

Comment: Also related: [HTTP 1.1 Expect header handshake](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15569589)

Comment: Thanks. Well from what I can tell there's no way to send a 100 continue requests from requests. But the current active socket should be accessible, or isnt' it? Then I could send the data directly through it.

Comment: You'd have to see if there is an active connection in the pool, yes. You just tried to access the `socket` module as imported by the `connectionpool` module, that's not going to help you.

Comment: I'm out of time for now; if you have a session object look at the adapters attribute; each adapter has a poolmanager object that may have current connections in the pool.

Comment: I'm confused by the question. `HTTP/1.1 100 Continue` is a response, not a request. Why would `requests` ever send it? Ref: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.3

Comment: @NikolaiTschacher you seem thoroughly confused. If you mean you wish to send the `Expect` header such that you can indicate to the server that you expect a `HTTP/1.1 100 Continue` partial response, then you can do so, it doesn't mean requests can or will change its behaviour. Read the issue Martijn linked and you may be able to understand some of why. It's a complex issue though.